# Get selected database inside migration when running manage.py migrate --database=database

Tags: django, django-models, django-migrations

I have a data migration which loads entries into my database as shown below:

```py
def load_groups(apps, _):
    Group = apps.get_model('auth', 'Group')

    Group(
        name='Admin'
    ).save()
    Group(
        name='Product Manager'
    ).save()
    Group(
        name='Developer'
    ).save()

migrations.RunPython(
    code=load_groups,
)
```

This code works fine when running `manage.py migrate`.

However if I run `manage.py migrate --database=copy` the migrations apply to the database with the alias `copy` but the `load_groups` section attempts to save to the database alias `default`.

I know I can set where to save to group creation to, but I can't seem to find a way to access the name of the database alias being used.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

settings.py:

```py
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django_prometheus.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    },
    'copy': {
        'ENGINE': 'django_prometheus.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'dev',
        'USER': '',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': '',
        'PORT': 3306,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'init_command': "SET sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES'"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: looks like your command is good. You go with no user / password and host, are you sure django can actually connect to your db? I think if it can't reach one, he'll take default

Comment: @Bestasttung Apologies, I removed the host, username and password because they are sensitive. Yes it can connect to the DB fine as it runs all the other migrations fine it is just my data migration running custom Python that is causing the issue.

Comment: so if you just leave the mysql et run migration it runs fine, but if you have both and precise --databases, it can't find it and applies it in the default one? So far, i can't what's wrong with your code, based on the doc.

Comment: So if I put my MySQL db as `default` and run `manage.py migrate` everything is fine. But if I change my db to something else (like `copy`) and run `manage.py migrate --database=copy` then the migrations will go to the MySQL database but creating model objects inside a migration will go to `default`